# Cannot password in SSKeychain in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keychain, osstatus

When i'm trying to save an Api Key to SSKeychain by
`[SSKeychain setPassword:strApiKey forService:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] account:@"payeverAuthKey" error:&error];`

i get following: 
`Error Domain=com.samsoffes.sskeychain Code=-34018 "errSecDefault" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=errSecDefault}`

Comment: Try enabling shared keychain on your proejct. Does it work? The keychain has been behaving pretty bizarrely for me on iOS 10, and enabling shared keychain is the one workaround that got things to work for me a good percentage of the time.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Yes, also found out that solves the problem, but that's strange as i didn't have it enabled in Xcode 7.
added an answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah it's a bug that has been lingering for a **long** time, at least on iOS 10 Beta 1. Hopefully Apple will solve this soon. I myself don't really like this workaround too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not related to SSKeychain, it is an issue with Keychain. 
Enabling Keychain Sharing in Capabilities tab in Xcode solves this problem.

[image]